What is the reason for using past perfect in following sentences


She had made me a nice cup of coffee.
He had lost his dog in the park yesterday.


What is the reason for using past perfect in following sentences

Please give more context, for example "She had made me a nice cup of coffee, when..." Without that, it would be better as "She made me a nice cup of coffee."

The wasn’t any extra information or clauses. Just these 2 examples were provided as examples of past perfect , and I’m wondering if they are correct or not .

No. They don't stand by themselves, but need context. Without that, there is no reason to use the past perfect tense.

Appreciate it

Can't be answered.  There is no special reason to use past perfect.  It is just like asking "why is it 'coffee' and not 'tea'"?  or "why is the first 'he' and the second 'she'?" There is no grammar reason to use past perfect,  No grammar reason not to use past perfect

We can't tell how this works without the context, but generally the reason is to locate the "temporal focus" or "story time" at a time in the past later than the events described.
So in the first example, the narrative is focussed on a time later than her making the tea - perhaps when you are sitting drinking the tea. Often that time will already have been established, but starting a narrative with a past perfect is a useful device for establishing the temporal landscape - that there is a time the author is setting the story at, and that she made tea before that time.

Thanks a lot for your attention
